# Transparent part of my image shows up black

Tags: shaders, transparency, color

I would like to ask for help figuring this one out.

I have a grayscale image with a black background, and I have the same image but colorized and with transparent background.

I need a mixed shader so that the black is gradually transformed into transparent, while the grayscale is transformed to a color scale.

I tried with a ColorRamp but the alpha becomes black in the render even if I have a blend mode to "alpha blend".

It would be nice if I could symply use the grayscale image texture for it, but I could also use on where I load the two images and mix them.

Thanks for any help

**Edit**: I add the real RGBa if you want to try it with this images

[image: Dog RGBA]
[image: DogGray]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). By 'gradually transform' you mean animation? Why not just use a mix shader?

Comment: Hello :) I do have it, and I can mix them but as I say, the alpha from the RGBa becomes black and I have not been able to change that ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

Works just fine with the provided images.
Perhaps you forgot to connect the alpha channel?

[image]

Comment: That was exactly it! Silly me, I was using Diffuse BSDF instead of principled. Can't believe I spent like 30 min trying to figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :). I'd reccomend *Images as Planes* addon shipped with blender - it connects alpha channel automatically

Comment: Oh yes I use it. Indeed I just load the image as a plane and it comes with a nice shader to begin with. I am super new at this. You've helped me a lot. I am doing a video to explain my scientific paper, and it is coming along nicely now!

Comment: Good luck with your paper! You don't _need_ to use Principled necessarily, you can use the Diffuse BSDF and a Transparent BSDF, and use the alpha to mix between the two with Mix Shader. It doesn't hurt to use Principled, though! Especially if you prefer the more realistic results.